# Glide error with ?attr/color use in drawable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I have ic_test.xml in drawable folder.

**ic_test.xml**

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24">
        <path
            android:fillColor="?attr/black"
            android:pathData="M19,13H13V19H11V13H5V11H11V5H13V11H19V13Z" />
    </vector>
```

when I use Glide for load, Glide not work because I use **"?attr/black"** for **"fillColor"**, if I use **"@color/black"**, Glide is work. anyWay can fix this?

```
Glide.with(getContext())
                .load(R.drawable.ic_test)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().transforms(new CenterCrop()))
                .into(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="black">#000000</item>
```

`?` is only for accessing `styles.xml` not `colors.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I do this, I add black in style

Answer (score 1):

use **@android:color/black**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/black"
    android:pathData="M19,13H13V19H11V13H5V11H11V5H13V11H19V13Z" />
```